# Unable to write to file in Python when using Flask in mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm running a Flask app using Python 2.7.6 on mod_wsgi 3.4. OS is Ubuntu 14.04. I'm unable to write to a file. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    f = open('/var/www/jcapp/foobar', 'r+')
    f.write('hello world')
    f.close()
    jcapp.run()
```

Apache site config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mysite.co
 WSGIDaemonProcess jcapp
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/jcapp/jcapp.wsgi
 <Directory /var/www/jcapp/>
        WSGIProcessGroup jcapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
 </Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias /notify /var/www/jcapp/jcapp.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/jcapp/>
    WSGIProcessGroup jcapp
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Can someone please tell me where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Does the `www-data` user have write access on that directory?

Comment: Yes. For testing purposes, I gave chmod 777 access to both jcapp directory and foobar file.

Comment: Could you include the Apache2 site config file? What OS are you using?

Comment: Added it in the question description itself.

Comment: Hmm...move the code out of the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block?

Comment: Yes. That works. Moving the code into route handler functions works. Can you please tell me why it wasn't working in the if-block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only write to the file if `__name__ == '__main__'`, which it does not when you run with mod_wsgi instead of `python app.py`.

Move the code outside of the `__name__` guard.

Or use a separate entry point if you need to do some setup before running your app.  Point mod_wsgi at this entry point instead.

`wsgi_app.py`:

```
from myapp import jcapp as application

with open('/var/www/jcapp/foobar', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello world')
```